# Is there a function that returns the UNICODE value of a character? (C++)

Tags: c++, unicode, char, value-of

I need a function that returns the UNICODE value of a character.
In java **String.valueOf('а');** is valid. 
Is there equivalent function in c++?

Comment: A UNICODE character is (possibly) just a `uint16_t` anyway.

Comment: @RogerRowland So what about utf 32? also utf8, not exactly a `uint16_t`.

Comment: @Waldermort lol, as I finished typing I wondered who would open that can of worms!

Comment: @RogerRowland lol. Trust me, all this unicode, locale and whatnot have been doing my head in these last few days.

Comment: Errr... define "character". A unicode character is a unicode character, and its value is itself. Unless you mean something like "Unicode mnemonic", like "LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A".

Comment: One possibility would be to use [`btowc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/btowc) (though I'm uncertain enough about what you want, that it's essentially impossible to say for sure).

Comment: @JerryCoffin The only thing he tells us is what he would do in Java.  For which the exact equivalent in C++ is `u16string( 1, u'a' )`.  (Whether that's what he really wants, however, is unclear; his text suggests that he doesn't actually know what the Java function does.)

Answer (score 2):

The question really doesn't make sense in the context of C++.
You have to define what you mean by the Unicode value (which
encoding format)—Java insists on UTF-16, but arguably
UTF-8 or UTF-32 make more sense.

Also, despite the name, the Java function does *not* change or
reinterpret any values.  It's the exact equivalent of `wstring(
1, L'a' )` in C++, at least on machines where `wchar_t` is
UTF-16.  (In C++11, you can force UTF-16, with
`std::u16string( 1, u'a' )`.)